# Configurando o git para rede local

Tags: git

Tenho uma máquina aqui na empresa onde fica o código fonte, seria o nosso servidor local. Temos 2 programadores, que tem acesso ao fonte que compartilha dessa máquina.

Nas configurações do GIT em cada máquina se eu quiser colocar por exemplo git user.name, user.email, não deveria considerar apenas a máquina que estou fazendo isso?

Pois atualmente a cada nova configuração que eu faço sempre considera a última, por exemplo se na máquina do programador 1 eu definir user.name “João” e der um git config –list irá aparecer o name como joão, mas e na máquina do programador 2 definir user.name “Maria” e em seguida der um git config –list vai apresentar o name como Maria.

Eu quero saber como configurar cada máquina como um único usuário, pois cada programador irá fazer commit nos arquivos que estão alterando.

Por exemplo se o programador 1 altera o arquivo index, eu imagino que o programador 2 não deveria ter acesso ao arquivo até que a alteração seja concluída e caso o programador 1 der um GIT status o arquivo nem deveria aparecer como em alteração, apenas se o programador 2 fizer isso, talvez deveria utilizar branche para resolver esse conflito?

Comment: Mas se aparece "João" para programador 1 e "Maria" para o programador 2, já está cada qual configurado com seu usuário. E se o programador 1 editou o arquivo `index`, quando verificar o status, deve aparecer o arquivo modificado, mas para o programador 2, não, pois a alteração não foi subida ao servidor. Resumindo, não está claro seu problema.

Comment: Com [tag:svn] você consegue fazer o bloqueio de arquivo até que a alteração for concluída, mas não é recomendado isso. serio.

Answer (score 2):

O git não é bem assim como você imagina. Ele é um Sistema de controle de versão descentralizado e não centralizado, como aparentemente você está fazendo, compartilhando arquivos em rede.

Você pode até ter um servidor de git na sua rede, porém cada programador baixará o repositório do servidor para sua máquina e trabalhará localmente de forma isolada. Ao final, enviará a alteração para o servidor.

Estude mais a respeito no [livro oficial online](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Primeiros-passos-Sobre-Controle-de-Vers%C3%A3o) disponível em português.

Comment: Aaa entendi ai ao final da alteração daria um push pro servidor local?

Comment: Exato! Conceitos como branch e merge também são importantes para um trabalho em equipe mais produtivo.

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado Murillo